# Extract text from <> tags searching a certain pattern

Tags: sql, regex, function, teradata

I have this pattern. I want to extract `HISTORY0` pattern for `STATUS`, It's `WAS` value (in the tag `<SINGLE>`) and `IS` value (in the tag `<MARRIED>`) 
and segregate into new columns:

```
HISTORY0:<NAME>WAS<ABC>IS<XYZ>
HISTORY1:<NOMBRE>WAS<ABC>IS<XYZ>HISTORY0:<ID>WAS<123>IS<456>
HISTORY1:<ID>WAS<123>IS<456>HISTORY0:<STATUS>WAS<SINGLE>IS<MARRIED>
HISTORY1:<ESTADO>WAS<SOLTERO>IS<CASADO>
```

I tried using REGEX but it's being very complicated.. Please help.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question following those guidelines - you will get much better responses!

Comment: New columns or new rows? What is the expcted result?

Comment: may be this will help you https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1624028-3077-1.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RegExp_Substr:

```
RegExp_Substr(col, '(?<=HISTORY0:<STATUS>WAS<)[^>]+',1,1,'i')       -- WAS
RegExp_Substr(col, 'HISTORY0:<STATUS>WAS<(\w+)>IS<\K[^>]+',1,1,'i') -- IS

"(?<=.....)" is a lookbehind (without adding it to the result)
"\K" means, forget the match up to here
```

But a bit simpler with the undocumented

```
RegExp_Substr_gpl(col, 'HISTORY0:<STATUS>WAS<(\w+)>IS<(\w+)>',1,1,'i', 1) -- WAS
RegExp_Substr_gpl(col, 'HISTORY0:<STATUS>WAS<(\w+)>IS<(\w+)>',1,1,'i', 2) -- IS
```

Using the same RegEx @Tim had in his deleted answer